# How can you prevent Linux from drawing Java program?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, java

1.) I want to run a Java program on a linux device. It might be a Raspberry Pi, still I'm interested in a more generell solution of my problem, if possible.

2.) This Java program makes use of 3D-graphics. But I don't own any source.

3.) I want to run this program on a low-end machine, but it's not required to "see" the program. The machine will be remote-controlled.

As far as I know when using only the java.awt.* package, a thread called the *Event-Dispatching-Thread* get's started and every call of the AWT-library is managed by this thread which himself hands those requests to the underlaying operating system.

Since AWT is only a small part of the JFC. **What is beneath the Swing components etc. and does the "work"?**

**Is there a way to make the operating system ignore any of those requests to save system ressources e.g. RAM, CPU, energy consumption?**

Edit: I don't like my title, any improvements highly appreciated.

Edit2: With ignore I mean that the operating system just doesn't do any calculations, but without letting the program know about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making awt run in [headless mode](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) by setting the `java.awt.headless` system property.

For example, if your java program was an executable jar file `program.jar`, you could start it with:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar program.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `Java` programs are designed to not be modified at runtime due to security reasons. Check if the program provides any switches try `program --help` or `program -h`.

Since you're not having the source code to modify it to your liking, the only thing you can do is to change the [`niceness`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/change-the-nice-value-of-a-process/) or [`renice`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-unix-linux-process-priority/) the running process. (Or check [cpulimit](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cpu-usage-limiter-for-linux/))

There is a chance getting a better answere when you tell us which program you're actually trying to run on your raspi.

Finally there is [raspberrypi.stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) board which you could check additionally - but don't cross post the same question here and there!